# Basic loop in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use a macro I made in excel in Google Sheets. This is my first time using this and I have it kinda working but seems real slow compared to excel. Not sure whats going on and making it so slow.

I have messed with the loop a bunch of different ways but still seems slow. It should only be running about 20-50 times.

The loop should be: 
When A is < B 
then A = A+1

```
function loopscript() {  
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;  
    var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
    var num1 = activeSheet.getRange(3, 2).getValue();  
    var num2 = activeSheet.getRange(4, 10).getValue();  
    for(var i=1;num2 < num1;i++) {  
        var num3 = activeSheet.getRange(6, 2).setValue(i);  
        num2 = activeSheet.getRange(4, 10).getValue();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Without understanding the contents of your Spreadsheet it's impossible to make any sense out of your script.  Num3 is set equal to a range which is not a value.  There is no indication that num1 and num2 ever change based upon the information available within your script.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Your equation seems to be if(num2<num1) {

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value for the cell `num2`. Every time the loop runs it's getting it's own value from (4,10).
You could write it like this:

```
      num2++;
      activeSheet.getRange(4, 10).setValue(num2);
```

Also, I recommend you to declare the num3 variable outside the loop to not do it every time:

```
      var num3;
      for(var i=1;num2 < num1;i++) {  
          num3 = activeSheet.getRange(6, 2).setValue(i);  
      ...
```

Or not declaring it at all if you only want to see the counter in the Sheet: `activeSheet.getRange(6, 2).setValue(i);`

You could also consider using a `while` loop:

```
      var i = 1;
      while (num2 < num1){
      num2++;
      ss.getRange(4, 10).setValue(num2);

      activeSheet.getRange(6, 2).setValue(i);
      i++;
      }
```

You can put the setvalue outside the loop too, after `num2` and `num1` are equal.